# Conditions for single post

Tags: categories, menus

I want to add `current-page-anchestor` when a single post is browsed. I was looking for that function code and tried many, but with not success yet. Now I am thinking I can do it that way, then it would work. Like

**if ... the post from this category ... then add `current-page-anchestor`** etc, something like that. So then, when I visit my single post, my menu will be highlight too .

You can also see details what I am looking for [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/142590/keep-active-class-in-post-page)

My current nav code is below

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'my_css_attributes_filter', 100, 1);
add_filter('nav_menu_item_id', 'my_css_attributes_filter', 100, 1);
add_filter('page_css_class', 'my_css_attributes_filter', 100, 1);

function my_css_attributes_filter($var) {
  return is_array($var) ? array_intersect($var, array('current-menu-item', 'current-menu-ancestor')) : '';

}
```

Comment: Do you use WP native nav? Why don't you use default WP classes? I'm pretty sure WP ads such class to category menu item itself. What WP version do you use?

Comment: which default class you mean. can you please tell me details please. i am using all latest WP 3.9

Comment: OK. So if single post is displayed and it's in A category, then A category item will have these classes: "menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category current-post-ancestor current-menu-parent current-post-parent menu-item-XXX". You can use "current-post-ancestor current-menu-parent current-post-parent" to do what you want. But maybe I've misunderstood something.